# How to solve Reloading Issue in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp

I have some problem in port number for wamp server, it was occupied by my system process.

So, I changed the port number in http.conf to 81 and I completed one project in wordpress using port number 81 i.e., localhost:81

Now, I solved the port issue in wordpress and I changed the port into default (80).

All other local projects are working but the project developed in wordpress is not coming

It is redirecting from localhost/wordpress_project/
to localhost:81/wordpress_project/

I don't know why this problem occured to me?

There is no database connection problem.

Can anyone help me out here??

Comment: What is the Dashboard > Settings > Site URL set to? When you review the HTTP report, do you see a 301 redirect? Clear your cache?

Comment: have you changed siteurl and home url in database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this query, it will update your site url into new url.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://localhost:81/wordpress_project/', 'http://localhost/wordpress_project/') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://localhost:81/wordpress_project/','http://localhost/wordpress_project/');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://localhost:81/wordpress_project/', 'http://localhost/wordpress_project/');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://localhost:81/wordpress_project/', 'http://localhost/wordpress_project/');
```

Comment: may be htacess problem , have you try remove `.htaccess` ? create a copy of htaccess and remove it , see what happen if it is stop reloading it will be htaccess problem.

Comment: try installing a new wordpress and copy your theme `"wp-content/themes/someproject"` into a new wordpress theme folder, does it work ?

Comment: Not Necessary, it worked. it is not opened if I go directly to the site, But opened wp-admin and from that site its came properly. Thank You so much @noman,

Comment: may be you write in javascript to redirect to the hard coded url , try searching old url in folder, and my name is NOMAN ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure `siteurl` and `homeurl` of your website present inside `wp_options` table are having

```
localhost/wordpress_project/
```

instead of

```
localhost:81/wordpress_project/
```